# shortcode to output multiple images urls from media library id

Tags: permalinks, shortcode, media-library

I am writing some custom shortcode which outputs an images url from its ID. I would like the shortcode usage to be as follows:

[imagez id="211046, 211034"]

This is my code:

```
function image_thingy($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 1,
     ), $atts));

       return wp_get_attachment_url($id);

 }
add_shortcode('imagez', 'image_thingy');
```

With this I can only retrieve the url of the first ID only, and not multiple comma separated like in the above example. How could I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function image_thingy($atts) {
    // Merge attribtes from shortcode with defaults
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 1,
        ), $atts));

    // Extract id's from shortcode attributes and convert into an array
    $ids = explode(',',$atts['id']);

    $output = ''; // Variable that holds the shortcode output, at the end this will be returned

    // Loop through ids and fetch urls, and add a comma with a blank space
    foreach($ids as $id){
       $output .= wp_get_attachment_url($id). ', ';
    }
    // remove comma and blank space from the end of $output, and finally return $output
    return rtrim($output,', ');
}
add_shortcode('imagez', 'image_thingy');
```

The following code wraps the urls in `<img>` tags:

```
function image_thingy($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id' => 1,
        ), $atts));
    $ids = explode(',',$atts['id']);
    $output = '';
    foreach($ids as $id){
       $output .= '<img src="'. wp_get_attachment_url($id) . '"/> ';
    }
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('imagez', 'image_thingy');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get a syntax error, unexpected ';' on the line $output .= wp_get_attachment_url($id). ', ';

Comment: Improved and updated my answer. please check it now.

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. If you have the time, could you show me how to wrap each outputted url in an image tag?

Comment: Answer updated. See last code block for urls wrapped in `<img>` tag .

Comment: Perfect, That's great! Once again, only if you have time, could you please add some comments to the code to explain what is happening, I would like to learn more. Thanks again!

Comment: Comments added to first code block. If it helps, do up-vote the answer.